# Set repeat Local notification from date

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I want to set a repeat Local notification from date. For Example:

**StartDate: 25 June 2018**

**Todays Date: 21 June 2018**

I am stuck here. Below code is working but it is firing local notification from today not from 25 June 2018.

*Please have a look to my Local Notification function:*

```
func scheduleDosageLocalNotification(date: Date) {

        reminder.dosageIdentifier = "Dosage_Day"

        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.current

        let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        // Configure Notification Content
        notificationContent.title = "DOSAGE REMINDER"
        notificationContent.body = "Remember to take your TEST tablet dialy."

        // Set Category Identifier
        notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = Notification.Category.First
        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)

        components.hour = 08
        components.minute = 00


        let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
       // let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval!, repeats: true)

        // Create Notification Request
        let identifier = "Dosage_Day"

        let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)

        // Add Request to User Notification Center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to Add Notification Request (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
            }

            Utilities.saveContextForAppInfo()
        }

    }
```

It should repeat daily but from 25th of June.
**Thanks in Advance!!**

Comment: What parameter are you passing in your function - scheduleDosageLocalNotification?

Comment: its date : 25 June 2018 @Keyur Tailor

Comment: @DheerajD did you find any solution to this? if yes can you share?

Comment: @DheerajD I have checked all the solutions in this thread, all of them are wrong solutions, none of them worked. Can you please share any proper working solution if you found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
notification.subtitle = ""
notification.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()


notification.userInfo =  userInfo
notification.title = Title
notification.body = Message

let timeStr = time
let splitTime:[String] = timeStr.components(separatedBy: ":")
var dayComponent = DateComponents()
dayComponent.weekday = day as? Int //[1 to 7 get randomly]
dayComponent.hour = Int(splitTime[0])
dayComponent.minute = Int(splitTime[1])

let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dayComponent, repeats: true)
let lnMessageId:String = message
let dayRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: lnMessageId , content: notification, trigger: notificationTrigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(dayRequest, withCompletionHandler: {(_ error: Error?) -> Void in
if error == nil
{
//print("success")
}
else
{
//print("UNUserNotificationCenter Error : \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
}
})
```

If you want to test notification in your device,

Assume that next notification arrival at 25 June 2018 at 7.00 pm,
you will modify the date in device settings to 6.59 pm and 25 June 2018
or you will modify the date in device settings to 7.01 pm and 25 June 2018

scheduled notification will arrive at that time,

it's just the sample, it will repeat the notification in every specific weekday.  If you want to repeat the notification, you should set the anyone order like daily, weekly, every Monday etc.. otherwise, you should register the multiple notifications for the specific days(unorder days) with a unique id's.

refer this - [How to show multiple local notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947393/how-to-show-multiple-local-notifications/50947657#50947657)

If You want your notification to repeat daily but you want to skip the first occurrence. I don't think that's possible. there is a similar question

[Scheduling local notifications to repeat daily from tomorrow in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872429/scheduling-local-notifications-to-repeat-daily-from-tomorrow-in-swift)

Good Luck!

Comment: How I will get day value? dayComponent.weekday = day as? Int @ram

Comment: just randomly get the value from 1 to 7, if we get day 1, every day 1 user will get the notification at a scheduled time.

Comment: Thanks for your help... but you have not got my point I think.  @ram

Comment: I dont want to skip anything. I just want to start repeating notification after n days. Can it be done?

Comment: Thanks for your help @ram but I still not getting what I need

Comment: Hi!, I am using the same function but not getting notifications not even repeating notifications.

Comment: With this code the notifications would repeat only on the weekday you input at the selected time.

Comment: @DheerajD After these many I am still struggling with the same issue. If you have done it somehow, Can you share your solution here?. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below lines of code :

```
func scheduleDosageLocalNotification(date: Date) {

    reminder.dosageIdentifier = "Dosage_Day"

    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.current

    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    // Configure Notification Content
    notificationContent.title = "DOSAGE REMINDER"
    notificationContent.body = "Remember to take your TEST tablet dialy."

    // Set Category Identifier
    notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = Notification.Category.First
    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year,.hour, .minute], from: date!)//calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)

    components.hour = 08
    components.minute = 00


    let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
   // let notificationTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: interval!, repeats: true)

    // Create Notification Request
    let identifier = "Dosage_Day"

    let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: notificationContent, trigger: notificationTrigger)

    // Add Request to User Notification Center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Unable to Add Notification Request (\(error), \(error.localizedDescription))")
        }

        Utilities.saveContextForAppInfo()
    }

}
```

I have changed

```
var components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
```

to

```
 var components = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.month,.year,.hour, .minute], from: date!)
```

**Updated answer :**

```
func scheduleDosageLocalNotification(date: Date) {
reminder.dosageIdentifier = "Dosage_Day"
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
// Configure Notification Content
notificationContent.title = "DOSAGE REMINDER"
notificationContent.body = "Remember to take your TEST tablet dialy."
// Set Category Identifier
notificationContent.categoryIdentifier = Notification.Category.First
var components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute], from: date!) //calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
components.hour = 08
components.minute = 00
var notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
notification.category = "Dosage_Day"
notification.alertBody = "Local notification"
notification.fireDate = newDate
notification.repeatInterval = .day
print(notification)
print(notification.fireDate)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
Utilities.saveContextForAppInfo()
```

}
}

Happy Coding....

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Payal Maniyar. But it is nt repeating daily, its repeating every three days.

Comment: You have to fire Local notification write?

Comment: Check the updated answer if you want to implement local notification.

Comment: it is tradition way and deprecated

Comment: thanks for your help @Payal Maniyar but it is still not working for me.

Comment: Buy all the way. if today is 22 June and I want to set a repeat reminder starting from 25 June and from 25 June it will repeat daily. This is all I want but can't achieve it. Now I need to create 25 reminders starting from 25 of June. @Payal Maniyar

Comment: If you think this can be achieve just share the code or update mine. Or just me ping over Skype self.dheeraj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173624/discussion-between-payal-maniyar-and-dheeraj-d).

Comment: Hi!, I am using the same function but not getting notifications not even repeating notifications.